# Compilar codigo de C# para Windows desde Linux con Dotnet

Tags: c#, c, .net

he hecho una aplicación desde Linux para Windows con C# y quiero hacer una script en Bash para poder compilarla de manera autmática cada vez que quiera pero no se si puedo compilar C# para Windows desde Linux, y en el caso de que se pueda no conozco el comando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! hiciste una app .net en cual version? c# es solo el lenguaje, pero lo que importa es que version del framework usaste. De igual forma, todas se compilan exactamente igual...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.